# Best way to work with SQLite database inside application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

Sorry if it has been asked before, I can't find any question about this issue and I'm new to Obj-C so please be patient with me. Thanks in advance.

I have an application that works with `SQLite3` database, I want to work with the database inside the application, In every `UIViewController` I'm loading the data again from the database. The result is that the application is working a little bit slow in some views and more in others.

So, my question is, how to work with an `SQLite3` database? Is the best way is to load the `SQLite3` database inside an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary's` or to work from the app it self, each time to call the database and to save inside of it?

How can I know when to save the data inside the application if I'm using an `NSMutableArray` of dictionaries?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a lot upon the nature of your data, but when I'm using a database, it's generally because I have enough data that I would rather not use up precious memory, and therefore I tend to retrieve data from the database as I need it, view controller to view controller. Memory is one of the more scarce resources on iOS devices, so be careful before you decide to blithely hold data in a `NSArray`/`NSDictionary`.

Obviously, it's better if you don't have your SQL code littered throughout your app, so you probably want to encapsulate all of the data retrieval within a single class, if possible. That way you can change the data storage/retrieval mechanisms at some later date, as needed, and you don't have to change the code all over your program.

In terms of your observation that the app is a little slow retrieving data from the database, that's very strange, because retrieving data from a database is generally super quick. The only time I've had performance issues is when I was storing BLOB objects (e.g. for the PNG/JPG representations of images) in the database. So, now, unless I'm dealing with tiny, thumbnail-sized images, I'll store the images in the `Documents` folder and the database will only maintain the path for those image files.

But, getting back to your question, if your app is slow, you might want to submit a different question outlining the precise nature of the data and outline the nature of the performance hits you're suffering, and I'm sure we can try to help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you helped me a lot! Another question on the same subject, I have 3 or 4 method that creates an SQL connection to the database and each of those methods called 2-3 times in each view, this is not the reason that the app is slow? each method return another value.. what do you think?

Comment: I might make sure you're not opening and closing the database each time, but if you're not doing that, multiple database inquiries should not be a problem. I open the database, keep the connection open, and then interact with the database as the user interacts with the app or as required by the user interface. I have tableviews where each `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath` (which is called separately for each cell) results in a separate query to the database, and I have absolutely no performance issues.